# Silverlight Application Causes Internet Explorer To Close

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-3.0, crash

Some users of a silverlight application I develop are complaining that IE will close sporadically.  The sequence of events the users are doing are inconsequential, they are unable to reproduce the issue.  Our application uses isolated storage to save exceptions that occur on the client, but no exceptions appear in the log.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?  If so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: I guess it is common since both products are from Microsoft :)

Answer (score 0):

Hm that was long ago, but yes we do experience this sometimes. Either IE closes without a warning (whole browser), or Silverlight application inside tab, once again without a warning.

Hopefully SL 4.0 resolved this.